# PHP codeigniter does not return response for POST call

Tags: php, reactjs, codeigniter, fetch-api

I want get response from `PHP(CODEIGNIER)`, I am making POST calls to PHP file via `URL` since, everything is in cloud.

I am using `REACT JS` as Front-end

PHP FILE

```
    public function let_customer_login(){
        $strRequestType = $this->input->method();
        var_dump($this->input->post());
        $this->_decode_data();
        $str_mobile_or_email = $this->input->$strRequestType("sleLoginEmail",true);
        
        die("diers here");
        if(is_numeric($str_mobile_or_email)){
            $arr_validation_inputs = array('mobilenum'=>'sleLoginEmail','password'=>'sleLoginPassword');
        }else{
            $arr_validation_inputs = array('email'=>'sleLoginEmail','password'=>'sleLoginPassword');
        }
        $bln_or_arr_validation_response = $this->validate_inputs($arr_validation_inputs);
        
        if(is_array($bln_or_arr_validation_response)){
            $this->Customer_model->save_customer_login_history();
            echo json_encode(array('Status' => false, 'id' => $bln_or_arr_validation_response['id'], 'Errors' => $bln_or_arr_validation_response['error']), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }else{
            $int_customer_id = $this->Customer_model->customer_login_credentials_check();
            if($int_customer_id){
                $int_customer_groupid = $this->Customer_model->get_customer_group_based_on_customer_id($int_customer_id);
                $this->_set_session_for_customer_info($int_customer_id,$int_customer_groupid);
                $this->Customer_model->save_customer_login_history();
                echo json_encode(array('Status' => true, 'id' => "sleLoginEmail", 'Errors' => "success", "UserID" => $int_customer_id), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            }else{
                $this->Customer_model->save_customer_login_history();
                if(is_numeric($str_mobile_or_email)){
                    echo json_encode(array('Status' => false, 'id' => "sleLoginEmail", 'Errors' => "Mobile number and/or password is incorrect. Please try again or create new account."), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                }else{
                    echo json_encode(array('Status' => false, 'id' => "sleLoginEmail", 'Errors' => "Email address and/or password is incorrect. Please try again or create new account."), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my React file the below fn. is called when the button is clicked.

REACT FILE

```
    const letUserSignin = () => {
        const userCred = {
            "sleLoginEmail": formik.values.loginCred,
            "sleLoginPassword": formik.values.loginPassword
        }
        fetch("[url]/controller/let_customer_login",{
            method: 'POST',
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
           body: JSON.stringify(userCred),
           redirect: 'follow',
           mode: 'no-cors'
        })
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then( data => {
                    debugger;  // debugger is not hitting
                    console.log(data)
             })
        .catch( err => console.log(err))
    }
```

In console it throws error as

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2

GET REQUEST is working for the same file but POST REQUEST is not event hit the front-end.

Comment: kindly click on that error on console and it will show the error on file line no

Comment: ss it throws the mentioned error on spitulated line.. that line is pointing to .then block of fetch call